# Can i convert reports made in telerik reporting to any other reporting service

Tags: crystal-reports, telerik

I want to convert reports already made in telerik reporting service to any other reporting service like rdlc or crystal reports is it possible

Comment: Basically i don't want to purchase the telerik reporting service . On tail version it's giving me the trail message on all reports

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.

Depending on the type of data source, you may be able to reuse the data source (i.e., stored procedure, SQL Query, LINQ query). But, the bindings and designer are custom to the framework.